# Knockout js decomposing a sum of values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to think of the most elegant way to do this using knockout js.

Say I need to sum up 3 values, but the result sum can also be edited...how would you do this using knockout js?

I was thinking along the lines of setting deactivating the values that make up the sum when a user edits the sum value and reactivating them if the sum field is blank.

See this jsfiddle for a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/faHHB/

A similar example for decomposing a string using a computed observable exists in the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');

    this.fullName = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
                this.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); // Update "firstName"
                this.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); // Update "lastName"
            }
        },
        owner: this
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

**Edit**
For more clarity, I'm not sure how best to represent this situation:

Imagine the 3 fields represent value of your house, value of your car, value of your retirement savings and the sum represents total value of your assets.

All fields should be editable, and if a user enters the 3 values the total value should be calculated. The total value can also be directly edited (incase the user has other savings that aren't listed). I'm not sure of the best way to represent this...

When the user edits the total, options I can think of are:

1. Divide the total by 3 and populate the other values
2. Grey out the input values, and only allow users to change them again when the total value is blank.
3. Have a checkbox labelled calculate, which sums the value when ticked and lets the user edit when unticked.

I was trying to ask what the best way to represent this situation is as well as how to implement it using knockout. Apologies if I wasn't clear.

I've settled on approach 3 for now: jsfiddle.net/faHHB/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a view model that:-

Holds the sum as a separate observable

Has a flag to determine whether the sum should be automatically computed

Calculates the value of editedTotal when the flag is true, otherwise just returns the present value.

```
var testVm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  self.editedTotal = ko.observable(null);
  self.autoCalculate = ko.observable(true);
  self.calculatedTotal = ko.computed(function() {
     if ( self.autoCalculate() ){
         // Perform sum if still calculating
         var total = 0;

         for ( var i = 0; i < self.items().length ) {
           total += self.items()[i].Amount();  
         }

         self.editedTotal(total);
     }

     return self.editedTotal();
  });  
}
```

When you detect a direct edit on `self.editedTotal`, set `self.autoCalculate` to false.  At that point, your VM will not attempt to recalculate, and will just return the tracked value.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I follow: see http://jsfiddle.net/faHHB/5/. In your example autoCalculate remains true. I only intend to show the calculated total at any stage. In my example it only calculates the sum until I edit the the calculated total. I only want to display one sum: should that be editedTotal or calulatedTotal?

Comment: You should always display calculatedTotal.  However, if your user elects to edit the value, you should make sure that the input control you're using to capture their data binds to editedTotal.  When you've confirmed that the user has edited the total, simply switch autoCalculate off.

Comment: Okie im not sure if this is what u mean but this is the best I could come up with :) http://jsfiddle.net/faHHB/10/

Answer (score 2):

You should use read/write computed but the most important is to define rules how to parse sum. For example you can update only val1 when sum is changed:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.val1 = ko.observable(30);
    self.val2 = ko.observable(20);
    self.val3 = ko.observable(10);


    self.sum = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return parseInt(self.val1()) + parseInt(self.val2()) + parseInt(self.val3());
        },
        write: function(value) {
            self.val1(parseInt(value) - parseInt(self.val2()) - parseInt(self.val3()));
        }
    });
};
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/faHHB/1/

What behavior do you want to achieve when user changes the sum?

Comment: Thanks for the answer -  I'm still not 100% sure of the behaviour I want when the user changes the sum - its basically a scenario of you either enter the values to calculate the sum or enter the sum. From a usability perspective I don't think splitting up the sum will work very well - I would prefer ignoring or disabling the other inputs.

Comment: @woggles So you don't even know how you want the system to behave, but people are supposed to help you? If you don't even know what you want to do, how can anyone tell you how to do it?

Comment: @tyrsius part of the question was what the most intuitive behaviour in this situation is...have you heard of user interface design? Maybe I should have asked that in a separate question

Comment: @Tyrsius see edit for clarity - I realise I didn't ask very clearly

Comment: @woggles That does help, and yes I've heard of UI/UX design. My point was that someone gave you a working answer and you seemed to turn it down because it didn't fit criteria you hadn't specified, and implied that you didn't even understand entirely *why* you were rejecting the answer. It just rubbed me the wrong way.

Comment: @Tyrsius point taken - the confusion stems from my not being specific enough in my question. I should have spent more time figuring out exactly what behaviour I wanted. I wasn't rejecting his answer, I just didn't accept it because it wasn't quite what I was looking for...in fact I voted him up because it was still helpful :)